How does the geometry of the set R(P) govern the 'smoothness' of sieve bounds?
Consider the problem of estimating sums over primes, where the sequence being summed satisfies specific Type I and Type II estimates controlled by parameters $\gamma$, $\theta$, and $\nu$.  Let $R(P)$ be a set of vectors in  $\mathbb{R}^k$ (for varying $k$) with components in $(0,1-\gamma)$ that sum to 1 and have no proper subsum in $[\theta, \theta + \nu]$.  It has been established that the "mass" of $R(P)$ can exhibit both smooth and discontinuous behavior as the parameters $\gamma$, $\theta$, $\nu$ are varied.  This, in turn, governs the behavior of optimal sieve bounds $C^\pm(\gamma, \theta, \nu)$ for the prime sum.
Can we develop a quantitative measure of the "smoothness" of the changes in $R(P)$ as $P$ varies, and relate this measure to the rate of change of the sieve bounds $C^\pm(P)$?

What are some references for "it has been establshed that..."? Also, perhaps you could sketch what is meant by the rather generic/vague phrase "this in turn governs the behavior of..."
